# Unable to insert data into database using php script

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

I am using Sql server 2012 procedure to execute using php and the result should be store into table on sql server only.
I am facing this issue, I can fetch the data from php code but when i insert that data into table only one value is inserted.I can see different values on my screen
when i run php script.but back to data base only first value is inserted.
I am not getting where i am going wrong.
please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC  ))

{

     if($obj['Bank_Name']!= $obj['Bank_Name_old'])
            {       
            $obj['company_code']; 
            $obj['Account_Code'];
            $obj['Bank_Name']; 
            $obj['Bank_Name_old'];
            $obj['field_name']='Bank Name';

             if($obj['field_name']='Bank Name')
            {   
                $old=$obj['Bank_Name_old'];     
                $new=$obj['Bank_Name']; 
            }
                    $query="insert into vns_db.dbo.client_details_log (company_code,client_id,field_name,original_value,new_value) values ('".$obj['company_code']."',
                            '".$obj['Account_Code']."','".$obj['field_name']."','$old','$new')".'<br>'; 
                            $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
                            echo $res;
                            echo $query;
            }
```

this is php script output

[image]

Comment: remove .'<br>' from $query variable

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.'<br>'` from your query. It's a HTML line break, SQL can't handle it.

You can always use [`sqlsrv_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) to check for errors if a query doesn't work as intended:

```
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
if ( $res === false ) {
  echo "Error in SQL query:";
  var_dump( sqlsrv_errors() );
}
```